# M:N relationship without a junction table

Tags: database-design, junction

Given two tables Student(id,name) and course(course_id,course_name). These two tables have a M:N relationship.

- Is there any way to implement a M:N relationship in relational database without using a junction table?
- If not in relational database then in any other database model?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to implement a M:N relationship in relational database without using a junction table?

Sure, just store an array of "pointers"<sup>1</sup> in one of the tables. You can use either an array type natively supported by your DBMS, or encode it in VARCHAR.

**However**, this will horribly denormalize you database (you'll be [violating the 1NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1NF#Atomicity)), and I can't imagine why would anybody do that in practice.

Is there any specific reason you want to avoid a junction table?

---

*<sup>1</sup> Values of the key in the other table.*